# Using data structures and algorithms, other than queue and FIFO, for handling and prioritizing requests

Tags: algorithm, web, data-structures, request

Using queue and first-in-first-out algorithm seems like a standard way of dealing with requests to servers/databases/services. But could any other data structures and algorithms be used for dealing with large quantities of requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an article at http://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=2991130 "Scaling Synchronization in Multicore Programs" which goes into the detail of reducing the locking costs when multiple cores are trying to update the same FIFO queue.

If different users or different requests have different priorities then a FIFO queue won't do, and you need something that takes account of the priority. I have often seen ordered maps used for this, such as TreeMap and std::map or std::multimap. It's not the use case these are designed for, but people know how to use them, and they are typically highly optimised, so they can be faster than most people's attempt at implementing a more specialised data structure.

Comment: "I have often seen ordered maps used for this" [Ouch](https://youtu.be/fHNmRkzxHWs?t=2708) "and they are typically highly optimised" - maybe they are optimized, but **not** for performance.

Comment: In the single processor single core case I saw some software that was using std::map as a priority queue, with a significant amount of time spent inside std::map. I benchmarked std:map as a priority queue against my own very straightforward implementation of a more specialised alternative - it might have been a heap, but I forget the details now. I didn't see a performance gain that would have justified modifying the original program.

Comment: "I benchmarked std:map as a priority queue against my own very straightforward implementation of a more specialised alternative - it might have been a heap, " Heh, benchmarking a tree structure against another tree structure? I promised myself I'll benchmark an "insertion sort" in a vector against the RB-tree implemented by std::map. I might go with an in-memory b-tree type - the CPU caches react against normal RAM pretty much the same way the RAM reacts against disk accesses, so why not?